# convert value to correct format text

Tags: java, groovy, jira

I'm using script runner in Jira to send customised emails. There is a value returned which I need to format correctly. The value is issue creator, I just want the first name returned. At present I'm getting whatever the person puts in full name. I need to edit the outcome so that anything after the first space is ignored. How can I do this?

**Example:**

```
 Dear $issue.creator = Dear Claire Jones
```

Results in Claire Jones, where I just want Claire to be returned. I'm not a developer so please ignore my ignorance, but this seems to be running with Groovy if that helps.

I have successfully managed to change a date format with the following, if that gives you any clues. (`${issue.getCreated().format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')})`

Thanks

Comment: Dear ${issue.getCreator().split("\\s+")[0]}

Comment: Thanks, thats looks to make sense but I receive this error:

No signature of method: com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.workflow.postfunctions.SendCustomEmail.tr() is applicable for argument types: (com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.workflow.postfunctions.SendCustomEmail$_getDescription_closure16$_closure27) values: [com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.workflow.postfunctions.SendCustomEmail$_getDescription_closure16$_closure27@26efb657] Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure), with(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: this last error is not related. it's probably on another line

Comment: No as if I remove this code there is no error. I think it maybe related to the get. As $issue.creator brings back the value. But with this new code we are doing issue.getCreator() .

Answer (score 0):

Answer is...

${issue.getReporter().toString().split("\W")[0]}